# Right-angled triangle on a cylinder

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a question about trigonometry on the surface of a cylinder, and whether it's different from regular trigonometry on a plane.

Suppose I have a straight line of length $L$, and I tilt it by an angle $\alpha$. Then the horizontal and vertical projections of this tilted line are given by $L \cos \alpha$ and $L \sin \alpha$ resp.

Now, consider the equivalent problem on the surface of a right circular cylinder of radius $R$. Then the straight line is an arc of radius $R$. If I now tilt this arc by an angle $\alpha$, so that the arc still lies on the cylinder, what are the horizontal and vertical projections in the cylinder?

I tried doing this by unwrapping the cylinder onto a plane. But I got the same values as before: $L \cos \alpha$ and $L \sin \alpha$. Does this make sense? I would expect it to be different.

Comment: Why you expect it to be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised in hindsight that I should not expect the two answers to be different. The 'rolling' map that takes the plane to the cylinder, will also roll up the flat line and the tilted line. Moreover, the map is isometric and conformal, thus the angle between the two lines will remain the same.

I hope this question is useful to someone else in the future.